# ASP.NET WinSCP FileMask: only download certain filetype

Tags: asp.net-mvc, winscp

I'm downloading files from an FTP, with certain `FileMask` settings.

Currently, I'm just using this FileMask, to only download files from a specified date which works well (this also excludes subdirs!):

```
transferOptions.FileMask = "*>=" + date + "|*/";
```

Now I want to include ONLY `.jpg` and `.png` files, which I'm trying to do with this `FileMask`:

```
transferOptions.FileMask = "*>=" + date + "; *.jpg; *.png;|*/";
```

but this isn't working at all, I'm getting all kinds of filetypes. Is there any way to include ONLY these filetypes, or exclude all filetypes that aren't these two? I can't find any good solutions in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

This means, download all files newer than `date` **and** all `.jpg` and all `.png` files (and exclude subfolders):

```
transferOptions.FileMask = "*>=" + date + "; *.jpg; *.png;|*/";
```

---

While, you want to download all `.jpg` files newer than `date` and all `.png` files newer than `date` (and exclude subfolders):

```
transferOptions.FileMask = "*.jpg>=" + date + "; *.png>=" + date + "|*/";
```

---

Reference: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask